# How can i count how much items are in the table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, sql

I want to count all items are in the table for example table (see screenshot) (9,95: 3, 7,95: 2)

Here is my current code for reading out my table from the database.

[image]

Comment: You want to count total rows in the table?

Comment: what you want is total no of rows or colums in table?

Comment: Add some sample data and expected output. Also please mention the Database name.

Comment: Using...JS, HTML, PHP, jQuery? Please show what you have tried, and clarify what your goal is.

Comment: count how? With JavaScript? With SQL? With PHP? Very unclear with the tags.

Comment: i created a class wich returns the counts with this query ``` SELECT count(*) FROM products ``` and call the function in the table row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is Php code to count total number rows in a table. 
Lets assume we have table name as "products"

```
<?php

$products=$dbh->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM products");
$products->execute();
$productsCount = $staff->fetchColumn();
echo $productsCount;

?>
```